# show data into tableview from api when category cell and store cell is selected or only one from previous controller in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I am creating an app in which i have a controller in which i have a tableview which will show data from previous screen when cell from c ategory section or cell from store section are selected or only one is selected then when i click the double arrow button shown in app then it should navigate to tableview screen and should show all the data from category or store or both into tableview. in tableview controller i have an API which is POST and has a body parameter of 'term_ids' which contains value as 556,574 which is comma seperated means the former one is for category and latter one is for store or both ids contains category data or store data. Means i have to pass two ids and make them comma seperated and then pass to tableview controller

lets say in category screenshot i have selected first two cells and when i tap on double arrow button the selected cell data should pass to another screen whose screenshot is as below:

api link for category data: https://api.myjson.com/bins/wggld
api link for store data: https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fc46p
api link for coupons which i need to populate into tableview based on ID from category and store api link: https://api.myjson.com/bins/1c4dip

[image: screenshot for tableview screen]
my app screenshot for better understanding:
[image: screenshot for category screen]

code for my category screen and main home view screen where i want to populate data is as below:

code for categoryViewController is as below:

class CategoryViewController: UIViewController {

```
//MARK: IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var store_bar: UIViewX!
@IBOutlet weak var store_title: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var category_title: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var category_bar: UIViewX!
@IBOutlet weak var categoryColView: UICollectionView!

var selectedBtnIndex:Int = 1
var selectedIndexPaths = [Int]()
var tempStoreIndexPaths = [Int]()

var categoryData = [ModelCategories]()
var storeData = [ModelStore]()


var arrCategoryImages = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // register collectionview cell
    self.categoryColView.register(UINib(nibName: "CategoryCell1", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1")
    self.categoryColView.register(UINib(nibName: "StoresCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "StoresCell")

    self.store_bar.isHidden = true

    self.getCategoriesList()
    self.getStoreList()

}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

@objc func click_Category(sender: UIButton!) {

    if sender.isSelected == true {
        selectedIndexPaths.append(sender.tag)
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .normal)
        sender.isSelected = false
    }else {
        selectedIndexPaths = selectedIndexPaths.filter{ $0 != sender.tag }
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
        sender.isSelected = true
    }
}

@objc func click_store(sender: UIButton!) {

    if sender.isSelected == true {
        tempStoreIndexPaths.append(sender.tag)
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .normal)
        sender.isSelected = false
    }else {
        tempStoreIndexPaths = tempStoreIndexPaths.filter{ $0 != sender.tag }
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
        sender.isSelected = true
    }
}


//MARK: IBActions

@IBAction func categoriesData(_ sender: UIButton) {

    selectedBtnIndex = 1
    self.categoryColView.isHidden = false
    self.store_bar.isHidden = true
    self.category_title.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    self.category_bar.isHidden = false
    self.store_title.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgb: 0xAAAAAA), for: .normal)
    self.categoryColView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func storeData(_ sender: UIButton) {

    selectedBtnIndex = 2
    self.categoryColView.isHidden = false
    self.store_bar.isHidden = false
    self.store_title.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    self.category_bar.isHidden = true
    self.category_title.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgb: 0xAAAAAA), for: .normal)
    self.categoryColView.reloadData()

}

@IBAction func showHomeScreen(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
    if selectedBtnIndex == 1 {
      vc.couponId = categoryData[sender.tag].ID!
    }else {
        vc.couponId = storeData[sender.tag].ID!
    }

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
}

@IBAction func toSearchPage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchPageController") as! SearchPageController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
}

func getCategoriesList() {
    if ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.isReachable() {

        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StartProgress(view: self.view)

        APIClient<ModelBaseCategoryList>().API_GET(Url: SD_GET_CategoriesList, Params: [:], Authentication: true, Progress: true, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (modelResponse) in

            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

            if(modelResponse.success == true) {
                self.categoryData.removeAll()
                let resul_array_tmp_new = modelResponse.categories! as NSArray

                if resul_array_tmp_new.count > 0 {
                    for i in modelResponse.categories! {
                        if i.count != 0 {
                            if let image = UIImage(named: "\(i.slug!.uppercased())") {
                                self.arrCategoryImages.append(image)
                                self.categoryData.append(i)
                            }else {
                                self.arrCategoryImages.append(UIImage(named: "tickets")!)
                                self.categoryData.append(i)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                self.view.makeToast(modelResponse.message)
            }
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            self.categoryColView.reloadData()
        }) { (failed) in
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            self.view.makeToast(failed.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.makeToast("No Internet Connection..")
    }
}

func getStoreList() {
    if ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.isReachable() {

        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StartProgress(view: self.view)

        APIClient<ModelBaseStoreList>().API_GET(Url: SD_GET_StoreList, Params: [:], Authentication: true, Progress: true, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (modelResponse) in

            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

            if(modelResponse.success == true) {

                self.storeData.removeAll()
                let resul_array_tmp_new = modelResponse.store! as NSArray

                if resul_array_tmp_new.count > 0 {
                    for i in modelResponse.store! {
                        if i.count != 0 {
                            self.storeData.append(i)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                self.view.makeToast(modelResponse.message)
            }
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            self.categoryColView.reloadData()
        }) { (failed) in
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            self.view.makeToast(failed.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.makeToast("No Internet Connection..")
    }
}
```

}

//MARK: Delegate and Data Source Methods
extension CategoryViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if selectedBtnIndex == 1{
        return categoryData.count
    }else {
        return storeData.count
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if selectedBtnIndex == 1{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell1

        let dict = categoryData[indexPath.row]

        if let catName = dict.name, catName.count != 0 {
            cell.categoryName.text = catName
        }

        if let catOffersCount = dict.count {

            if catOffersCount == 1 {
              cell.catOfferCount.text = "\(catOffersCount)"+" "+"Offer"
            }else {
                cell.catOfferCount.text = "\(catOffersCount)"+" "+"Offers"
            }
        }

        cell.categoryImage.image = arrCategoryImages[indexPath.row]

        cell.btn_click.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btn_click.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.click_Category), for: .touchUpInside)

        if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath.row) {
            cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .normal)
            cell.btn_click.isSelected = true
        }else {
            cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
            cell.btn_click.isSelected = false
        }

        return cell
    }else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "StoresCell", for: indexPath) as! StoresCell

        let dict = storeData[indexPath.row]

        if let storeName = dict.name, storeName.count != 0 {
            cell.storeName.text = storeName
        }

        if let storeOfferCount = dict.count {
            cell.storeOfferCount.text = "\(storeOfferCount)"+" "+"Offers"
        }

        cell.store_btn_click.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.store_btn_click.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.click_store), for: .touchUpInside)


        if tempStoreIndexPaths.contains(indexPath.row) {
            cell.store_btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .normal)
            cell.store_btn_click.isSelected = true
        }else {
            cell.store_btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
            cell.store_btn_click.isSelected = false
        }

        return cell
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if selectedBtnIndex == 1{
       return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 3, height: 93)
    }else {
        return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 2, height: 48)
    }
}
```

code for homeView COntroller is as below:

import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

```
var couponsData = [ModelCoupons]()

var couponId = Int()


@IBOutlet weak var homeTblView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.homeTblView.register(UINib(nibName: "HomeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeCell")
    self.post_CouponsData()

}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

//MARK: IBActions
@IBAction func toCategoryScreen(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

@IBAction func toSearchPage(_ sender: UIButtonX) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchPageController") as! SearchPageController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

func post_CouponsData() {
    if ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.isReachable() {

        var params = [String : String]()

        params ["term_ids"] = "\(self.couponId)"

        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StartProgress(view: self.view)

        APIClient<ModelBaseCouponsList>().API_POST(Url: SD_POST_CouponsList, Params: params as [String:AnyObject], Authentication: true, Progress: true, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (modelResponse) in

            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

            if(modelResponse.success == true) {

                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

                let dict = modelResponse.coupons
                for i in dict! {
                    self.couponsData.append(i)
                }

            }else {
                self.view.makeToast(modelResponse.message)
            }
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            self.homeTblView.reloadData()

        }) { (failed) in
            self.view.makeToast(failed.localizedDescription)
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
        }
    }else {
        self.view.makeToast("No internet connection...")
        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
    }
}
```

}

extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return couponsData.count
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCell
    let dict = couponsData[indexPath.row]

    if let postTitle = dict.postTitle, postTitle.count != 0 {
        cell.ticket_postTitle.text = postTitle
    }
    if let postContent = dict.postContent, postContent.count != 0 {
        cell.ticket_postContent.text = postContent
    }
    if let storeName = dict.stores, storeName.count != 0 {
        cell.storename.text = storeName
    }

    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"

    let datee = ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.ConvertStingTodate(forApp: dict.validTill!)
    cell.ticket_ValidDate.text = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: datee)

    cell.ticketImageView.tintColor = .random()
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 339.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 339.0
}
```

}

Comment: @Muhammad Maaz Ul Haq sir can you help me with this problem